# Swift: How to refresh tableview without lag (UIRefreshControl)

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

Filling my table view with objects from a MYSQL database using PHP and JSON to Swift 3. I have a pull down to refresh function but when I'm pulling down to refresh it lags mid way for a second and then continues (like the wheel won't spin for a second).

How can I update my tableview smoother because I'm guessing as I add more content to the database in the future the bigger the lag. I currently have 12 objects in my database so imagine with 100+ objects.

In viewDidLoad

```
// Pull to Refresh
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        myTableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        print("iOS 10")
    } else {
        myTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        print("iOS 9 or iOS 8")
    }
```

Then pull to refresh function

```
// Pull to Refresh
func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    // Fetching Data for TableView
    retrieveDataFromServer()

    // Stop Refreshing
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

// Retrieving Data from Server
func retrieveDataFromServer() {

    // Loading Data from File Manager
    loadData()

    let getDataURL = "http://example.com/receiving.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {
        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

        // Clear the arrays
        self.followedArray = [Blog]()
        self.mainArray = [Blog]()

        // Looping through jsonArray
        for jsonObject in jsonArray {

            if let blog = Blog(jsonObject:jsonObject as! [String : Any]) {

                // Check if Identifiers Match
                if followedIdentifiers.contains(blog.blogID) {
                    self.followedArray.append(blog)
                } else {
                    self.mainArray.append(blog)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
    }
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: you are calling loaddata() in retrieveDataFromServer() Try calling loadData() and Api mechanism in. background Queue. lag occur because it take some seconds to load all parameters of loadData() and Api mechanism

Comment: @iOSGeek even if I comment `//loadData()` it still lags the same

Comment: Dont comment just use a async mechanism and try using because for me this always Worked should I comment basic async mechanism?

Comment: you are fetching from server in main thread synchronously. That is why it lags. Try to follow some tutorial and fetch it in asynchronously.

Comment: @iOSGeek it was just to show that the problem is not in `loadData()`

Comment: okay but use async method to get data asynchronously so no lag

Comment: @iOSGeek how would I go about this? I use async but for images using SDWebImage

Comment: what kind of Data you are displaying in TableView is it images ? yes you can use SDWEbimage or kingfisher in Swift but it is for downloading images yes if your tableView elements are images just use it. always prefer backGround queue for Download task . release mainThread free

Comment: @iOSGeek its json data from a mysql database, I use SDWebImage for the images.

Comment: yes okay use that library for images and for reloading use async queue

Comment: @iOSGeek I'm already using it for images, I just dont know how to use async for the JSON data

Comment: check comment please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Spinner.isHidden = false
    Spinner.startAnimating()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
       loadData()

    let getDataURL = "http://example.com/receiving.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {
        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

        // Clear the arrays
        self.followedArray = [Blog]()
        self.mainArray = [Blog]()

        // Looping through jsonArray
        for jsonObject in jsonArray {

            if let blog = Blog(jsonObject:jsonObject as! [String : Any]) {

                // Check if Identifiers Match
                if followedIdentifiers.contains(blog.blogID) {
                    self.followedArray.append(blog)
                } else {
                    self.mainArray.append(blog)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
    }

        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {

            myTableView.reloadData()
            self.Spinner.startAnimating()
            self.Spinner.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: My api mechanism would be `retrieveDataFromServer()` code?

Comment: Gave me a crash saying `This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.`

Comment: sorry I reloaded tableView in background Queue here just reload tableView in main Queue mean just cut this line " myTableView.reloadData()" above "DispatchQueue.main.async" and write "myTableView.reloadData()" just before "self.Spinner.startAnimating()"

Comment: Welcome anytime For help

Comment: Last startanimating() call should be stopanimating().

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the apple sample code at the following location:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Couple of suggestion :

Don’t  show the data at cellForRowAtIndexPath: method ‘cause at this time cell is not displayed yet. Try to use tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method in the delegate of UITableView.

Re-Use single instance of cell/header/footer even if you need to show more.

Let me know if anything specific is needed.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your retrieveDataFromServer() is blocking the main thread, and therefore causing the lag. Try wrapping it in an async block

```
// Pull to Refresh
func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    // Fetching Data for TableView
    retrieveDataFromServer { [weak refreshControl] in
        // This block will run once retrieveDataFromServer() is completed

        // Reload data
        myTableView.reloadData()

        // Stop Refreshing
        refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
}

// Retrieving Data from Server
func retrieveDataFromServer(completion: (() -> Void)?) {

    // Loading Data from File Manager
    loadData()

    let getDataURL = "http://example.com/receiving.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {
        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

        // Clear the arrays
        self.followedArray = [Blog]()
        self.mainArray = [Blog]()

        // Looping through jsonArray
        for jsonObject in jsonArray {

            if let blog = Blog(jsonObject:jsonObject as! [String : Any]) {

                // Check if Identifiers Match
                if followedIdentifiers.contains(blog.blogID) {
                    self.followedArray.append(blog)
                } else {
                    self.mainArray.append(blog)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
    }

    // Calls completion block when finished
    completion?()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the lag you're experiencing is due to the network request being executed synchronously on the main thread:

```
let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
```

Network requests are slow and should almost certainly be done off the main thread. The solution here is to move the networking call to a background thread so the main (UI) thread doesn't get blocked (lag).

So how do you do that? Well that is a large question with many different answers.

I highly recommend you spend some time learning about multi-threaded programming (also known as concurrency) in Swift. Going through this [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1) should give you a good foundation.

Then it's probably a good idea to learn about URLSession which is used for performing asynchronous network requests in iOS apps. Again Ray Wenderlich has a great [starter tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/158106/urlsession-tutorial-getting-started).

Finally... here is a quick and dirty solution for you. It's "hacky" and you probably shouldn't use it, but it will probably fix your lag issue:

```
func retrieveDataFromServer() {

    // Loading Data from File Manager
    loadData()

    let getDataURL = "http://example.com/receiving.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    // Move to a background queue to fetch and process data from network.
    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        // Don't touch anything related to the UI here.
        do {
            let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
            let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

            // Create new temp arrays to process json
            var tempFollowedArray = [Blog]()
            var tempMainArray = [Blog]()

            // Looping through jsonArray
            for jsonObject in jsonArray {

                if let blog = Blog(jsonObject:jsonObject as! [String : Any]) {

                    // Check if Identifiers Match
                    if self.followedIdentifiers.contains(blog.blogID) {
                        tempFollowedArray.append(blog)
                    } else {
                        tempMainArray.append(blog)
                    }
                }
            }

            // Jump back to main (UI) thread to update results
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("success")
                self.followedArray = tempFollowedArray
                self.mainArray = tempMainArray

                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
                // This reload is probably not necessary, but it was
                // in your original code so I included it.
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```